# Label specific amount of points along line in QGIS

Tags: qgis

In QGIS with this expression I can place points along a line at a given distance

```
with_variable (
'no',
20,
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (0,@no-1,1),
        line_interpolate_point( 
            $geometry, 
            length($geometry) / @no * @element 
            + length($geometry) / @no / 2
```

))))

But is there a way to put a label with the distance from the origin
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `repeating labels`?

Answer (score 3):

Using Geometry Generator, you just create a new style **for each feature**. So all the points along the line are in fact one single (multipoint) feature/style and because of that, you can't label them individually.

Use [`Geometry by Expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) instead with your expression to create actual points, convert [`Multipart to Single parts`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts) and then use the following expression to label these points (replace `line` with the name of your line layer):

```
line_locate_point(
    overlay_nearest('line',$geometry)[0],
    $geometry
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because there is no point layer, Points re just a style created with the generated geometry

Comment: What doesn't work? If you follow the instructions, you generate a point layer, based on your expression and you can than label this layer. Exactly because a geometry generator created style is not a layer, you won't be able to label these points individually. Or didn't I understand a point?

Comment: My question was how to create the label without creating a new layer with the points, I understand that that is not possible, right?

Comment: Indeed, you need to create another layer for that.